# Drawing into a scaled CGContext results in all-white image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

If I draw an image into a CGContext, it works as expected when I later make an image out of it. But when I want to mirror this image by scaling the X-axis by -1, the same code that produces the image produces an all-white image - ie. doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(aspectFitSize.width), height: Int(aspectFitSize.height), bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
context.scaleBy(x: -1, y: 1) // <-- this line causes the problem; it's fine without it, but I want to mirror the image...
context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect.init(origin: .zero, size: aspectFitSize))
let image = context.makeImage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mirrored the image across the Y-axis. So the point (1, 0) is now (-1, 0). That means everything is (almost certainly) drawing outside the bounds, in the negative half of the X plane.

You need to also translate the context by the width of the screen if you want "the right hand edge" to be at zero. Something like:

```
context.translateBy(x: bounds.width, y:0)
```

(untested)

Comment: oh, duh. of course. I had the mental model of `UIView.transform` in my head. Thanks!